# jQuery.noConflict Tabs with Revolution Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs, jquery-ui-slider

Im having some problems with tabs on my website. The revolution slider works like a charm, but my tab widget is displaying all the tabs content instead on each tab content itself. You can check the error on: http://www.microloads.com at the bottom of the page.

The code for the tab widget on **custom.js** is this:

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

function tab_widget(tabid) {

    var $sidebarWidgets = $('.sidebar-widgets-wrap');
    var $footerWidgets = $('.footer-widgets-wrap');

    $( tabid + " .tab_content").hide();
    $( tabid + " ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show();
    $( tabid + " .tab_content:first").show();

    if( window.location.hash != '' ) {

        var getTabHash = window.location.hash;

        if( $( getTabHash ).hasClass('tab_content') ) {

            $( tabid + " ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
            $( tabid + ' ul.tabs li a[data-href="'+ getTabHash +'"]').parent('li').addClass("active");
            $( tabid + " .tab_content").hide();
            $( getTabHash + '.tab_content').show();

        }

    }

    $( tabid + " ul.tabs li").click(function() {    

        $( tabid + " ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");     
        $( tabid + " .tab_content").hide();
        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("data-href");
        var $selectTab = $(this);
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(600,function(){
            if( $selectTab.parent().parent().hasClass("side-tabs") ) {
                if( $(window).width() < 768 ) { if( $().scrollTo ) { jQuery.scrollTo( activeTab , 400, {offset:-20} ); } }
            }            
        });
        return false;

    });

}
```

How can i fix this? thanks

Comment: It has nothing to do with `jQuery.noConflict()` because there is a javascript error in your code at line `879`. Have you declare `$` for other use before that line?

Comment: i used this on the header: <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.themepunch.plugins.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.js"></script>. Thats the only scripts used before that

Comment: the code in 879 is this: <script type="text/javascript">
                            $(document).ready( function() {
                                
                                tab_widget( '#tabwidget-1' );
                            
                            });
                        </script>

Comment: I suggest you change `$` in line 879 to `jQuery` to see if the problem is solved, if so, the `$` namespace is polluted.

Comment: it worked. Thanks a lot =)))))))). Put that as an answer so i can vote as the right one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with `jQuery.noConflict()` because there is a javascript error in your code at line `879`.

Always avoid polluting the global namespace, that will be a disaster for javascript code.